# Consider if $\int_{1}^{\infty}[\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-\sin(\frac{1}{x})]\text dx $ converges.

Tags: calculus

Consider if $\int_{1}^{\infty}[\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-\sin(\frac{1}{x})]\text dx $ converges.

I took a substitution $t=\frac{1}{x} $. Turn it into considering if $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+t)-\sin(t)}{t^2}\text dt $ converges.
And now since $\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(1+t)-\sin(t)}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{2} $, then it has no singular point hence it's an ordinary integrate. It follows that it converges.
Is it right ? Or any test would be more convenient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works, although I think perhaps the best way to think about this is in terms of Taylor series.  $\ln(1 + 1/x) = 1/x + O(1/x^2)$ and $\sin(1/x) = 1/x + O(1/x^3)$, so $\ln(1 + 1/x) - \sin(1/x) = O(1/x^2)$; since $\int_1^\infty 1/x^2 \,dx < \infty$, the integral converges.